# Probability of A > B AND A > C when A, B and C are random integers with different ranges but starting at 0.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I have 3 random integers A, B and C, along with 3 defined integers X, Y and Z:
A in [0, X]
B in [0, Y]
C in [0, Z]

All the values that A can take within its defined range are equiprobable. Same goes for B and C.
X, Y and Z are superior or equal to 0.

Let temporarily X = 2, Y = 2 and Z = 4 for the sake of clarity.

What is the probability that A > B AND A > C ?

A: 0, 1, 2
B: 0, 1, 2
C: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

We can see that only (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (2, 1, 0), (2, 0, 1) and (2, 1, 1) fit the proposition.
There are 3 * 3 * 5 possibilities, so the probability we are looking for is 1/9.

How can I express this for any X, Y and Z, all superior or equal to 0 ?

Please be lenient if you use factorials and sums as I am not proficient with those. I'm even worse with probability notations and vocabulary. My goal is to first express this mathematically in a simple-to-understand way, and then implement it programmatically as well as in OpenOffice Calc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:\left[0,X\right]\times\left[0,Y\right]\times\left[0,Z\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
be prescribed by:

$\langle a,b,c\rangle\mapsto1$ if $a>b\wedge a>c$
and $\langle a,b,c\rangle\mapsto0$ otherwise.

Then:

$P\left\{ A>B\wedge A>C\right\} =\frac{1}{\left(X+1\right)\left(Y+1\right)\left(Z+1\right)}\sum_{a=0}^{X}\sum_{b=0}^{Y}\sum_{c=0}^{Z}f\left(a,b,c\right)$

Leading to:

$P\left\{ A>B\wedge A>C\right\} =\frac{1}{\left(X+1\right)\left(Y+1\right)\left(Z+1\right)}\sum_{a=1}^{X}\left[\min\left(a-1,Y\right)+1\right]\left[\min\left(a-1,Z\right)+1\right]$

---

**Edit**:

$$\sum_{a=0}^{X}\sum_{b=0}^{Y}\sum_{c=0}^{Z}f\left(a,b,c\right)=\sum_{a=1}^{X}\sum_{b=0}^{Y}\sum_{c=0}^{Z}f\left(a,b,c\right)$$
because $f\left(0,b,c\right)=0$ for every $b,c$.

$$\sum_{a=1}^{X}\sum_{b=0}^{Y}\sum_{c=0}^{Z}f\left(a,b,c\right)=\sum_{a=1}^{X}\sum_{b=0}^{\min\left(a-1,Y\right)}\sum_{c=0}^{\min\left(a-1,Z\right)}f\left(a,b,c\right)$$
because $f\left(a,b,c\right)=0$ if $b\geq a$ or $c\geq a$.

From here we are allowed to substitute $f\left(a,b,c\right)=1$ and
$$\sum_{b=0}^{\min\left(a-1,Y\right)}\sum_{c=0}^{\min\left(a-1,Z\right)}1=\left[\min\left(a-1,Y\right)+1\right]\left[\min\left(a-1,Z\right)+1\right]$$

However: $\min\left(a-1,Y\right)+1=\min\left(a,Y+1\right)$ and $\min\left(a-1,Z\right)+1=\min\left(a,Z+1\right)$
so we could also write the RHS (more elegantly) as:

$$\min\left(a,Y+1\right)\times\min\left(a,Z+1\right)$$

Comment: Thanks! The conclusion is pretty clear. As expected I have trouble understanding how you went from "then" to "leading to" in a mathematically foolproof way.
I eventually deducted the following, more from observation than rigorous step by step math:
$P\left\{ A>B\wedge A>C\right\} =\frac{1}{\left(X+1\right)\left(Y+1\right)\left(Z+1\right)}\sum_{a=1}^{X}\left[ \min\left(a,Y+1\right)\right]\left[\min\left(a,Z+1\right)\right]$
Are there edge cases where I am wrong, or are we both correct at all times ?
I'm interested in the step by step math, if you don't mind explaining.

Comment: Your solution is essentially the same as mine. Even a bit more elegant I would say.

Comment: Thanks! Everything is clear now. Following track, I think the probability of B > C when our previous equation is not verified should be (A <= B OR A <= C) AND B > C: 
$P\left\{ B>C\wedge P\left\{A<=B\vee A<=C\right\}\right\}=\frac{1}{\left(X+1\right)\left(Y+1\right)\left(Z+1\right)} \sum_{b=1}^{Y}\min\left(b,Z+1\right)\times\left(X+1\right)$
Edit: This is wrong