# Probability of (A <= B OR A <= C) AND B > C when A, B and C are random integers with different ranges but starting at 0.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I have 3 random integers A, B and C, along with 3 defined integers X, Y and Z:
A in [0, X]
B in [0, Y]
C in [0, Z]

All the values that A can take within its defined range are equiprobable. Same goes for B and C.
X, Y and Z are superior or equal to 0, and they are independent from one another.

Let temporarily X = 2, Y = 2 and Z = 4 for the sake of clarity.

What is the probability that (A > B AND A > C) is false, AND B > C is true ? I guess it translates to $P\left\{ \left( A\le B \vee A\le C\right) \wedge B>C\right\}$.

A: 0, 1, 2
B: 0, 1, 2
C: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

We can see that only (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (2, 2, 0) and (2, 2, 1) fit the proposition.
There are 3 * 3 * 5 possibilities, so the probability we are looking for is 8/45.

How can I express this for any X, Y and Z, all superior or equal to 0 ?

We determined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337467/probability-of-a-b-and-a-c-when-a-b-and-c-are-random-integers-with-differen) the probability (A > B AND A > C).
Please be lenient if you use factorials and sums as I am not proficient with those. I'm even worse with probability notations and vocabulary. My goal is to first express this mathematically in a simple-to-understand way, and then implement it programmatically as well as in OpenOffice Calc.

Thanks!

Comment: No, it's $P\{(A \le B \vee A \le C) \wedge B > C\}$.  You have an extra $P$ in there that makes no sense.

Comment: Indeed, I put it in only because for some reason the code didn't work with regular parenthesis but did when I added a nested P. The culprit must have been some other mistake that I corrected inadvertently when adding the P. Thanks. It's the first time I use that kind of code.

Comment: I edited the question to precise that X, Y and Z are independent from one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the condition $A \le C$ is redundant: given $B > C$, $A \le B \vee A \le C$ is equivalent to $A \le B$.  So what you want is simply $P\{A \le B \wedge  C < B\}$.  Now it's a bit complicated to count the possibilities because  you haven't told us how $X, Y, Z$ are related.  I'll do one case, where $X \le Y \le Z$.  The others are similar.

Given $B = b$ (with $0 \le b \le Y$), we want to count the possibilities for $A$ and for $C$ with $A \le b$ and $C < b$.  Since I'm assuming $Y \le Z$, any value for $C$ in the interval $0 \ldots b-1$ is a possible value for $C$, i.e. there are $b$ possible values for $C$.  On the other hand, for $A$ we also have to take into account the requirement $A \le X$.  There are two cases:

1. If $b \le X$, all values for $A$ in the interval $0 \ldots b$ are possible; there are $b+1$ of these, and thus $(b+1)b$ possible values for the pair $(A,C)$.
2. If $b > X$, the possible values for $A$ are in the interval $0 \ldots X$; there are $X+1$ of these, and thus $(X+1)b$ possible values for the pair $(A,C)$.

Now to count the possiblities for $(A,B,C)$, we have to add these all up:
$(b+1)b$ for $b$ from $0$ to $X$, and then $(X+1)b$ for $b$ from $X+1$ to $Y$.
In summation notation this is

$$ \sum_{b=0}^X (b+1)b + \sum_{b=X+1}^Y (X+1)b = \sum_{b=0}^X b^2 + \sum_{b=0}^X b + (X+1) \sum_{b=X+1}^Y b $$

Now using the formulas $$\eqalign{\sum_{j=0}^n j &= \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\cr
\sum_{j=0}^n j^2 &= \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\cr}$$

the number of possibilities for $(A,B,C)$ works out to 
$XY^2/2 - X^3/6 + Y^2/2 + XY/2 + Y/2 + X/6$.  Divide this by the total 
number $(X+1)(Y+1)(Z+1)$ to get your probability.

Comment: Quickly because I won't have time to delve into your answer before an hour or two: X, Y and Z are not related in any way. I said they are defined as opposed to random, but they are actually independent variables to be retrieved by a program at the time of calculation. Thank you for the help because any good example like this is going to let me learn a bit more, even if it doesn't explicitly cover other cases than $X\le Y\le Z$ I hope I can figure it out from there.

Comment: They are numbers, so (in any particular instance) they are in some order.  You just don't happen to know that order in advance.  But the calculation will depend on the actual values, and in particular on the order.

Comment: So there is no simpler way than to cover all 6 cases derived from the sorting order ? Ok, I'll give it a try soon and validate your answer when I understand everything. Thanks again :)

Comment: This is hard for my limited experience with probabilities and sums. I didn't expect this problem to be so much more difficult than the previous one. First things first, how do you find out that $A\le B$ is redundant ? $P\left\{ \left(A\le B\vee A\le C\right)\wedge B>C\right\}$ should translate to $P\left\{\left(B>C\wedge A\le B\right)\vee \left(B>C\wedge A\le C\right)\right\}$. The right part amounts to $A\le C<B$, which means $A<B$. From there I lack knowledge of the rules or something else to figure out $P\left\{A\le B\wedge C<B\right\}$.

Comment: Sorry, typo: I meant $A \le C$ is redundant.  Given that $B > C$, $A \le C$ implies $A \le B$, so $(A \le B) \vee (A \le  C) = (A \le B)$.

Comment: Nice! Using minimums and your simplified proposition, I was able to streamline the solution greatly. Is it correct to use $\min$ in math though ? For my situation it is ideal, but I would like to get better using regular math and probabilities tools as opportunities arise. Your solution sounds more academic so it is a good opportunity. That said, is my solution correct too ? $$P\left\{ \left( A\le B \vee A\le C\right) \wedge B>C\right\}=\dfrac{\sum_{b=1}^{Y} \min\left[\min\left( b+1, Y\right) ,X+1\right]\times\min\left( b,Z+1\right)}{ \left( X+1\right)\left( Y+1\right)\left( Z+1\right)}$$